# How to array(per line) textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

Good morning! Please some body help or give some sample code about how to read text value (per line)

```
<body onLoad="displayResult()">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<?php $query2="SELECT * FROM upload1 WHERE NAME='xmlsample1.xml'";
$result1=mysql_query($query2);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
?>
<form action="">
<textarea id="validxml" rows="50" cols="100">
<?php echo $row['CONTENT']; ?>
</textarea>

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Verify XML" onClick="validateXML()" />

</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the value of `textarea`and split `newline`

```
console.log(document.getElementById('validxml').value.split("\n"));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/9nB2D/)

Answer (score 1):

`connect.php` should be kept on a separate, secure web page.

```
<?php 
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>
```

Now on your other page:

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php'; $db = db();
$sq = $db->query("SELECT * FROM upload1 WHERE name='xmlsample1.xml'"); $ta = '';
if($sq->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $sq->fetch_object()){
    $ta .= "<textarea class='validxml' name='{$row->name}'>{$row->content}</textarea>";
  }
}
$sq->free(); $db->close();
?>
```

Now just echo `$ta` into your HTML. Of course, I wouldn't even use a `<textarea>` to just output code, unless you want your user to be able to edit it.